# How to get the number of days of difference between two dates on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

I need to get the number of days contained within a couple of dates on MySQL.

For example:

- Check in date is `12-04-2010`
- Check out date `15-04-2010`

The day difference would be 3.

Answer (score 302, accepted):

What about the **[DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)** function ?

Quoting the manual's page :

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2
>   expressed as a value in days from one
>   date to the other. expr1  and expr2
>   are date or date-and-time expressions.
>   Only the date parts of the values are
>   used in the calculation

In your case, you'd use :

```
mysql> select datediff('2010-04-15', '2010-04-12');
+--------------------------------------+
| datediff('2010-04-15', '2010-04-12') |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    3 | 
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

But note the dates should be written as `YYYY-MM-DD`, and not `DD-MM-YYYY` like you posted.

Comment: yeah i forgot about the date format when i made the question ;p
thank you

Comment: P.S. YYYY-MM-DD is ISO 8601 standard, so everyone should use this. Very practical.

Comment: **Note**: The first argument must be greater than the second argument for `datediff()` method, otherwise it'll return negative value.

Answer (score 55):

Note if you want to count **FULL 24h days** between 2 dates, datediff can return wrong values for you.

As documentation states:

> Only the date parts of the values are used in the calculation.

which results in

`select datediff('2016-04-14 11:59:00', '2016-04-13 12:00:00')`

returns 1 instead of expected 0.

Solution is using `select timestampdiff(DAY, '2016-04-13 11:00:01', '2016-04-14 11:00:00');`
(note the opposite order of arguments compared to datediff).

Some examples:

- `select timestampdiff(DAY, '2016-04-13 11:00:01', '2016-04-14 11:00:00');`
  **returns 0**
- `select timestampdiff(DAY, '2016-04-13 11:00:00', '2016-04-14 11:00:00');`
  **returns 1**
- `select timestampdiff(DAY, '2016-04-13 11:00:00', now());` **returns how many full 24h days has passed since 2016-04-13 11:00:00 until now**.

Hope it will help someone, because at first it isn't much obvious why datediff returns values which seems to be unexpected or wrong.

Comment: weird that the arguments are flipped around between `datediff()` and `timestampdiff()`.

Comment: I have one question how to use other timestamp format like DD-MM-YYY?
select timestampdiff(DAY, '13-04-2016 11:00:00', '13-04-2016 11:00:00');

Answer (score 19):

Use the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function.

Example from documentation:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2007-12-31 23:59:59','2007-12-30');
    -> 1
```

Answer (score 8):

I prefer [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) because you can easily change the unit if need be.

Answer (score 6):

Get days between Current date to destination Date

```
 SELECT DATEDIFF('2019-04-12', CURDATE()) AS days;
```

output

### days

```
 335
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT md.*, DATEDIFF(md.end_date, md.start_date) AS days FROM  membership_dates md
```

output::

```
id  entity_id    start_date            end_date             days

1   1236      2018-01-16 00:00:00     2018-08-31 00:00:00    227
2   2876      2015-06-26 00:00:00     2019-06-30 00:00:00   1465
3   3880      1990-06-05 00:00:00     2018-07-04 00:00:00   10256
4   3882      1993-07-05 00:00:00     2018-07-04 00:00:00   9130
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more accurate value than just the rounded up number of days:

```
select timestampdiff(minute, min(date_col), max(date_col))/1440 from table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,STR_TO_DATE(date_format('2018-01-01', '%d-%m-%YYYY'),'%d-%m-%YYYY'), '2020-01-01') TOTAL_DAYS
```

> TOTAL_DAYS: 730 days