# SQL days since DATEDIFF()

Tags: sql, datediff

I'm trying to count the days since a post was made. SQL saves the date and time in the table `pins` in the column `time`. The format is 2013-11-20 10:36:01.

I have read up on how to do this on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

and have come up with the following code:

```
<?php 
$dayssince = mysql_query("SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'CURDATE()','$pinDetails->time') AS DiffDate     FROM pins WHERE id ='$pinDetails->id'");
?>
<?php echo $dayssince; ?>
```

Where `$pinDetails->time` is the datestamp in the database.

However, nothing shows, not even an error number.

EDIT:

I got it to working using this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '$pinDetails->time')");
$dayssince = mysql_result($result, 0);
```

Comment: 1. [Stop using w3schools.](http://www.w3fools.com) 2. [Search on StackOverflow for your problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql)

Comment: I searched on Stack first. I even read the question edited into my own "This question may already have an answer here", but they are different since I'm using variables and not numbers, and CURDATE() wouldn't work.

Comment: Server version: 5.0.96-log

Comment: Your code points to SQL Server (the driver) yet you've noted what appears to be a MySQL version number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using SQL Server function syntax in MySQL. The correct syntax for MySQL's [`DATEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) is:

> ```
> DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
> ```

For example,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '2013-11-10 23:59:59')
```

Returns

```
> 10
```

You can replace the static date in the example with the name of the column from your table.

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/010cf/1)

**Use the DBMS documentation**

Comment: All I'm getting is "Resource id #58", I've tried changing all aspects of the code. I think when I'm calling the query I'm experiencing the problems.

Comment: I don't know what your complete code looks like. Use pastebin or similar and provide a link for us.

Comment: I got it working using this code: $result = mysql_query("SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), '$pinDetails->time')");
$dayssince = mysql_result($result, 0);

Comment: You could have just done this on the application side.