# How do I use Datediff between multiple dates in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datediff

I want to find out how often my customers place an order within 7 days after their last order.
I know how i can select customer ids, with the dates of their purchases, but how do i select the differences between these multiple dates? datediff probably, but how?

I am looking for a result like this:

```
customer_id,  date1 | date2 | date3, diff date3-date2 | diff date2-date1
```

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT c.id,GROUP_CONCAT(DATE(co.date_order))
FROM customer c
JOIN customer_order co ON co.id_customer=c.id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql

Comment: Basically you need to use a query variable to keep track of the date from the "previous" record, e.g `select @prev := min(order_date) from ...` to initialize, then `select datediff(order_date, @prev), @prev := order_date` to derive a field with the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the syntax for DateDiff function:

```
DATEDIFF(dateFormat,startdate,enddate)
```

Where dateFormat is either day,month or year based on your requirement.
Modify your query and pass your values inside the function and you can acheive your result. Hope this helps.