# How to Calculate Days Gap Between End Date and Start Date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have

CustID  Contract start  contract ends 
100     2013-09-30       2013-12-31
100     2014-02-28       2014-12-31

The calculation should give me the Gaps in days between contracts

I am trying to do the below which gives me the Contract duration:

SELECT CustID
    , StartDt
    , EndDt
    , FIRST_VALUE(DateDiff(DAY, StartDt, EndDt)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY CustID

```
ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING) C
```

FROM tblContracts

However, I need the calculation between the end date of the last contract and the start date of the second contract

Any Suggestions would be really helpfull

Comment: Please tag the correct rdbms. Is it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: MySql or SQL Server? tried or not? read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  or didn't?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of days of difference between two dates on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql)

Comment: Using of DATEDIFF, you can calculate the date difference.

Comment: Once you've figured out which RDBMS you're using, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use DateDiff
[MySQL DateDiff Function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-datediff.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below query helps :

```
 select datediff(day,StartDt,EndDt) from <tablename>;
```

Comment: What RDBMS is this?

Comment: This is SQL server