# mysql query with datediff between expyredate and now date

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

i'm having some problem to write correctly a sql query before perform it through php file writing right code for it.

Actually i have a table sql ( tblperson ) with some person name ( as name ) and their birthday date in it ( yy/mm/dd ), i need to view persons that have made birthdays in last 15 days till today.

I have tried some different queries without success as:

```
SELECT name, birthday FROM tblperson 
WHERE  DATEDIFF(birthday,(SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY))


SELECT name, birthday  FROM tblperson 
WHERE  DATE(bb) = DATE_SUB(birthday,(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY))
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql

Comment: You weren't far from a solution, your first query uses `DATEDIFF()`, all it needs is something to compare the result with, like `DATEDIFF(...) <= 15`. Also don't forget to swap the arguments of `DATEDIFF()` and get rid of the `DATE_SUB()`, minor things like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The birthday problem is tricky because of the year component.  Here is one method that *almost* works:

```
select name, birthday
from tblperson 
where format(bb, '%m%d') <= format(curdate(), '%m%d') and
      format(bb, '%m%d') >= format(curdate() - interval 15 day, '%m%d');
```

The problem is the first 15 days of the year.  Here is one method that handles that explicitly:

```
select name, birthday
from tblperson 
where (format(curdate(), '%m%d') > '0115' and
       format(bb, '%m%d') <= format(curdate(), '%m%d') and
       format(bb, '%m%d') >= format(curdate() - interval 15 day, '%m%d')
      ) or
      (format(curdate(), '%m%d') < '0115' and
       format(bb + interval 15 day, '%m%d') <= format(curdate() + interval 15 day, '%m%d') and
       format(bb + interval 15 day, '%m%d') >= format(curdate(), '%m%d')
      )
```

Comment: your firt soution works great, only i can't create a correct php script to execute it, i have tried to do

$sql = "select `domain`,`expirydate`\n"

    . "from tbldomains\n"

    . "where format(`expirydate`, \'%m%d\') <= format(curdate(), \'%m%d\') and\n"

    . "      format(`expirydate`, \'%m%d\') >= format(curdate() - interval 15 day, \'%m%d\')";

but it doesn't works, could you help me for it?
Thank you so much.

Comment: If you use double quotes to define the string, I don't think you need to escape the single quotes.