# how to substract two datetimes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I want to count landingpage views that happened 7 days before purchases. I used this query and its give an error

> "cannot load from mysql.proc. the table is probably corrupted"

```
SELECT count(l.customer_id) FROM customer_profiles.purchase p
left join landingpage_view lp on lp.customer_id = p.customer_id
where lp.datetime between date_sub(p.datetime(), INTERVAL 7 Day) and p.datetime()
and lp.customer_id = '14475'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of days of difference between two dates on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql)

Comment: Maybe your table is corrupted. Have you tried repairing it?

Comment: You have a database called customer_profiles?

Comment: Yes I have database called customer_profiles. Why?

Comment: no table is correct. when i run this query only then its give me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a syntactically correct query:

```
select count(*) 
from customer_profiles.purchase p join
     landingpage_view lp
     on lp.customer_id = p.customer_id
where lp.datetime between date_sub(p.datetime(), interval 7 Day) and p.datetime() and
      lp.customer_id = 14475;
```

The only change that would affect an error is in the `count()`.  The alias `l` is not defined.

Other changes:

- You might as well use `count(*)`.  There is no need to count a column because you seem to want a count of the rows.
- The `where` clause turns the `left join` into an `inner join`.  So, use the `join` the query is really doing.
- I am guessing that `customer_id` is a number, so I removed the single quotes.

Comment: its still give me same error "cannot load from mysql.proc. the table is probably corrupted"

Comment: @user6186914 . . . In that case, the table is probably corrupted.  Given that you were getting this error on a query that was syntactically incorrect, the corruption would appear to be in the metadata.  The only advise I can give you is to recreate the table (from either a backup or original data).