# Days Until Date

Tags: php

So in my database, I have "due" and a date.

It is defined like this: `$dues[$index] = $row["due"];`

I want to `echo` how many days until that date, I have looked around but can't seem to find it from a database.

Comment: It needs to be done in PHP? Mysql can do this pretty easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql

Comment: I am looking at that, but how would I set today's date?

Comment: With `CURDATE()`.

Comment: @chris85 I don't get that document. So, how would I go about doing it, if my date is defined as shown above?

Comment: @Tom http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0910e/2 Assuming this is mysql?

Comment: How would I put that into my code though? Saying I want to add it here: `<div class="collapsible-body"><span><?php echo $descriptions[$index]?></span></div>`

Comment: Please update the question with your code. Also use the `@` so notifications are sent.

Answer (score 0):

In the database, you have a due and a date field. What's in the date field? Today's date? Pretty sure you don't even need that there and can just use today's date with php to calculate and echo the days until that date without even changing the database.

Since you already stored all your due values inside of the dues array, you can just echo in a table:

```
$array_size = count($dues);
echo '<table>';
for($i = 0; $i < $array_size; $i++) {
    // if your date is in the format mm/dd/yyyy...
    // (you can change it however you want according
    // to how you formatted it in your database).
    $today = date('m/d/Y');
    $daysuntil = (strtotime($dues[$i])-strtotime($today)) / 86400;
    echo '<tr><td>Due: '.$dues[$i].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$daysuntil.' days left</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```