# PHP - Using STRTOTIME in CASE STATEMENT for two Columns in DB

Tags: php, mysql, case, strtotime

I want to use `strtotime`for two date columns in the database in the CASE statement.

This is the entirety of the php code.

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","nature526","thebase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,  "SELECT * FROM thetable ORDER BY curdate, case 

when mainissue = 'No Water Flow/Low Pressure' AND ((Previous - Recent) / Recent) * 100 >= 120 then 1
when mainissue = 'Leakage' AND address = 'Torko St. San Jose, Antique' AND ((Previous - Recent) / Recent) * 100 > 110 then 2
when mainissue = 'High Meter Readings' then 3
else 4
end asc");

 
echo " <center> <table border='1'>
 
<tr>
 
<th>Full Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Account Number</th>
<th>Box Number</th>
<th>Designated date for Repairs</th>
<th>Issue</th>
<th>Additional Information</th>
<th>Date Difference</th>


</tr>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 
    
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['actnum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['boxnum'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['reqdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['mainissue'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['textarea'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . (strtotime($row['curdate']) - (strtotime($row['recentdate']))) / 86400 . "</td>";

 
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);
```

So, the code above works but I want to include the two date columns `recentdate` and `curdate`. But its bugging me on where I should use the `strtotime` in the query. It works when I use it to echo the row.  `echo "<td>" . (strtotime($row['curdate']) - (strtotime($row['recentdate']))) / 86400 . "</td>";`. This formula works and outputs the difference between the date columns. `December 10, 2018` and `December 12, 2018` would output in the table `2`. Now, how would the `strtotime` work in the `CASE` statement so I could prioritize the highest difference?

It should theoretically look like these:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,  "SELECT * FROM thetable ORDER BY curdate, case 
when mainissue = 'No Water Flow/Low Pressure' AND  ((Previous - Recent) / Recent) * 100 >= 130  AND strotime(curdate - recentdate) / 86400 >= 1 then 1
when mainissue = 'No Water Flow/Low Pressure' AND ((Previous - Recent) / Recent) * 100 >= 120 then 2
when mainissue = 'Leakage' AND address = 'Torko St. San Jose, Antique' AND ((Previous - Recent) / Recent) * 100 > 110 then 3
when mainissue = 'High Meter Readings' then 4
else 5
end asc");
```

Comment: use `DATEDIFF()` for that:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2490177/4248328

Comment: @Alive to Die i see, where do I place it in the code exactly? Just to avoid confusion.

Comment: `AND (curdate - recentdate) / 86400 >= 3`. here

Comment: For completeness: try to find a working query using phpMyAdmin or another tool alone. That will help you to see that something like `strtotime` is a PHP method that does not work when you want to execute SQL calculations

Comment: @Alive to Die  when mainissue = 'No Water Flow/Low Pressure' AND ((Previous - Recent) / Recent) * 100 >= 130 AND DATEDIFF(reqdate - recentdate) / 86400 >= 1 then 1 is this how I place the DATEDIFF()? If so, it doesn't work because it gives me a mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given error.