# how can i loop two colum values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **leaves**.

```
----------
    id  FromDate    ToDate
    1  20-01-2019    22-01-2019
    2  15-01-2019    22-01-2019
    3  13-01-2019    20-01-2019
```

I want all dates between each column.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you post an example of what your output should look like? Can you also please add what you have already tried/what specifically is going wrong?

Comment: If you want to do with mysql you need a calendar table with all dates or procedure. It can't be done by query. Or do in php

Comment: @RAB `select leaves.id,leaves.LeaveType,leaves.ToDate,leaves.FromDate,leaves.Description,DATE_FORMAT(leaves.PostingDate, '%Y-%m-%d') PostingDate,DATE_FORMAT(leaves.PostingDate, '%H:%i:%s') PostingTime, leaves.AdminRemark, DATE_FORMAT(leaves.AdminRemarkDate, '%Y-%m-%d') AdminRemarkDate,DATE_FORMAT(leaves.AdminRemarkDate, '%H:%i:%s')  AdminRemarkTime,leaves.leave_status,leaves.emp_id,employee.* FROM leaves JOIN employee ON leaves.emp_id = employee.emp_id WHERE leaves.leave_status = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN $start AND $end`

Comment: This Question Already Answered Find Out Here..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql

Comment: @muhammed shanid in future please just edit your question with relevant information, dont put it in the comments. What you have there is basically unreadble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in your php code then you can do it by finding day count between two days and loop it to get the all dates between that two dates.

```
<?php

$date1 = "2019-01-13";
$date2 = "2019-01-20";

$date1 = strtotime("2019-01-13");
$date2 = strtotime("2019-01-20");
$datediff = $date2 - $date1;

$days = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

for($i=1;$i<=$days;$i++){
    echo $date1 = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date1 . ' +1 day'));echo '   <br>   ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below using `datediff()` function

```
select id, fromdate, todate,datediff(ToDate,fromdate) as days
from tablename
```