# How to calculate the duration date in SQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to calculate the remaining duration using an SQL query or using PHP. I have a table that has fields
 - `date_submit` (example 2019-12-01 09:40:22 ) and
 - `duration` ( example 30 days )

For example today is 2019-12-02 so the remaining duration is 29, how can I calculate this in SQL or PHP?

Comment: Why do you need to store the remaining duration while you already have the starting date?

Comment: it's like time limit, so i should know the remaining duration

Comment: I mean these two pieces of data are redundant: if you store the start date (and you know the end date), you don't need to **store** the duration. You need to calculate it to display it, to check if it's not too late, or whatever, but not to store it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the number of days of difference between two dates on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL query, you can use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to compute the remaining duration:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CURDATE(), DATE(date_submit) + INTERVAL duration DAY) AS remaining
```