# how can i calculate difference of two date values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

The difference of two date values ​​that are stored in the table is calculated and brought to the next column. My SQl Command Here

UPDATE `skuser` SET `count_day`=`date`-`paydate` WHERE`isactive`=0

Comment: What's the problem with that code? Also, how is this related to PHP?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the number of days of difference between two dates on mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490173/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-of-difference-between-two-dates-on-mysql)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd highly recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some pointers on how questions should be constructed.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question in readable form. There's no need to use images

Comment: Please also add a question to your question, such that others know what kind of help you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE `skuser` SET `count_day`=timestampdiff(day,date,paydate) WHERE`isactive`=1

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: The difference of two date values that are stored in mysql db. one field name date and second field paydate i use this code to calculate my countday in third field as per below this code                                                                                          
         UPDATE skuser SET count_day = timestampdiff (day, date, paydate) WHEREisactive = 1

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer** by editing it